# How to click tab of this hierarchy in Safari web browser using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, hierarchy

I don't know how to access this hierarchy as it seems really nested within the code. Would anyone know how I can click on the "Start" tab via Applescript?

[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctAqV.png)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I find to obtain a reference to a UI element from an object hierarchy is to use *System Events*' **`click at`** command, e.g.

```
tell application "System Events" to click at {300, 400}
```

If you run this command in *Script Editor*, it returns an object reference to whatever it finds at the coordinates you specify, in this case `{300, 400}`.

Therefore, what you can do is to hover the mouse over your `"Start"` object and obtain the mouse's coordinates.  This can be done by starting a screen capture using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, which brings up a set of crosshairs from which you can read the coordinates of the mouse cursor.  Then press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to cancel the screen capture, and use those coordinates to run a **`click at`** command (make sure the *Script Editor* window doesn't obscure the `"Start"` tab when you run the command).

Then, once you run it, the object reference (if it has one, which it ought to if it appears in the *Accessibility Inspector*) will appear in the results pane at the bottom of the *Script Editor* window, which you can copy and paste.  Here's an example:

[image: Screenshot on macOS]

Here, my mouse cursor is hovering over the tab in *Safari* in which I'm typing this answer.  I obtained the coordinates as being `{500, 73}`, then ran the command you see in *Script Editor*.  At the bottom is the object reference to the tab.  Note that the mouse doesn't need to remain hovering over the object in question as the coordinates specified will be used to issue the click and obtain a reference; I just kept my mouse there for illustrative purposes.